# How to use Firebase notification for two different users in the same App Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a `FCM` based `Application` in `Swift`. There are basically two different `Users` in my App, one is `Primary User` and second is `Family member`.

**Problem:** My problem is when I am switching the `User`, then need to restart the App in order to Post `FCM Token` of the `Switched User` to the Server. In `Android`, they are simply reopening the App while switching. So basically without doing the individual login, need to register the FCM Token for the `Switched User` Otherwise it is sending same `FCM Token` for both the `Users` and `notification` is not working for `Family member User`.

Can anyone please give the suggestions? Please let me know for any clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: When do they switch? Do they specify which type of user they want to be?

Comment: Yes its there during Switch Account.